# How to create a .NET executable through a .NET windows forms application?

Tags: .net, runtime, compilation, executable

As described in the title I would like to develop a **Windows Forms Application in .NET** that is capable of creating at run-time **another .NET command line or windows form executable** and let me save it to disk.

Do you have any ideas if it is possible and how to proceed?

**#Region "Some more info"**

I would like to create a form where the user can define a **path of an executable** and a **path for an icon/image**.

When he/she presses the build button the program create a **new .NET exe** that the user can save to the disk.

This exe's icon is the icon selected in during creation and when launched it starts the process selected during creation and exit.

Practically a mini launcher

**#EndRegion**

Thanks a lot,
Marco

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143973/where-would-you-use-c-runtime-compilation) might give you some answers on when and how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely - you can just use the [`CSharpCodeProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) class and get it to generate an assembly on disk. That's assuming you've got C# code you want to build, of course (e.g. code that the user typed in). There are similar providers for other languages - or you can decide at execution time using [`CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yzxs14d.aspx)

If you *don't* have C# code to compile, there are probably still ways of doing what you want - but you'll need to be specific about what you want this new executable to do.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Have a look at the [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways for this:

1. Creating a text file, containing the C# code of desired application. Compiling in using csc.exe
2. Creating classes and implementation dynamically using Reflection possibilitie